# How to add accounts to friends-app in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, online-accounts

When I opened the friends-app in Ubuntu Touch, it says:

> Setup Accounts
>   No online accounts configured, you can add one in System Settings

Doing a quick search on Google and AskUbuntu I don't figure out how to add accounts by command line, since the Ubuntu Touch doesn't have a System Settings for account in the user interface yet.

How to add accounts?

Comment: it's still beta/alpha which makes it off-topic.  that being said, i like it a lot and hope it matures.  try the mailing list (i'm also on the mailing list)

Comment: Which mailing list?

Comment: Third link https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+touch+mailing+list&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&aq=f&oq=ubuntu+touch+mailing+list&aqs=chrome.0.57.4147&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and raised it on the #ubuntu-touch IRC channel a couple of minutes ago.

You will have to use the terminal. If you already have setup ssh access you can use it. In this case you can skip the first part.

When connected via USB:

```
adb root
adb shell
ubuntu_chroot shell
su - phablet
```

The password for the user phablet is phablet

To create the online accounts type

```
uoa-create twitter <your twitter handle>
uao-create facebook <your facebook id>
```

the activation pages will be shown on your phone.

Comment: just figured out you can of course also use the terminal app. So no need for ssh or usb connection.